# ZPool export/import error

Tags: solaris, storage, zfs

A backup/clone script of ours was recently ran. It normally only clones the rpool and renames in rpoolA. Something must've changed as it found another one of our pools that it shouldn't have. It exported that pool unbeknownst to us. Later on when a coworker realized the other pool was missing he attempted to recover it but by creating a new pool with the same name and using the same lun instead of doing an import first.

It seems that since the new pool was created using the same name and same lun as the exported pool we cannot recover the original pool. We've tried destroying the newly created pool and running zpool import -D to see whats available and its only the newly created pool.

Does anyone know of any further recovery procedures? This was a newly installed system and this was our initial attempt at backing up that system so we are stuck without any data recovery.

Answer (score 3):

> creating a new pool

At this point, four labels (two at the beginning and two in the end of LUN) was overwritten by ZFS. This is strange because usually `zpool` detects older labels and they may only be overwritten by using `-f` option (force).

> Does anyone know of any further recovery procedures?

Not sure if they are. You'll need at least one alive uberblock (it is relocated in labels I told before) pointing to alive meta object set. They are most likely become destroyed after you created a new pool.

You may try to recreate them manually or simply dig into disk seeking for actual datasets. ZFS has [on-disk specification](http://www.giis.co.in/Zfs_ondiskformat.pdf), it may help you with that (but it won't be easy).

Comment: Unfortunately the -f was used as the technician working didn't realize entirely what was going on. I'll take a look at that link, thanks.

Comment: @timroberts: That technician needs a whack on the head. There is, in general a dearth of ZFS recovery tools. I'm writing one myself, but mostly relevant to my situation. Similarly, I've seen a lot of other Solaris/ZFS gurus write their own tools when the need has come for one.